# key does not contain a section: mergetool

Tags: git

I have no idea how I got to this point, I am trying to set kdiff3 as my merge tool but when I write `git config --global mergetool kdiff3` I get this error `key does not contain a section: mergetool` I checked my config list and unset a mergetool config that I had in there and so what I have now is:

```
$ git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
credential.helper=manager
user.email=nick@anideaforanapp.com
user.name=Naguib Ihab
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=https://omitted
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.report-visualisation.remote=origin
branch.report-visualisation.merge=refs/heads/report-visualisation
branch.report-visualisation_nvd3.remote=origin
branch.report-visualisation_nvd3.merge=refs/heads/report-visualisation_nvd3
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `git config --global merge.tool kdiff3`.

and the key `mergetool` is for configuration of the one merge tool, like `mergetool.kdiff3.path`